# RavenDB query doesn't work from C# but it works in RavenDB Studio?

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb-studio

Actually I want to delete all documents of a kind in a test procedure but I couldn't do that using `DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex` command , so I tried to see if I could query those entities , Here's my code :

```
var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080" };
            store.Initialize();
            var result= store.DatabaseCommands.Query("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
                new IndexQuery { Query = "Tag : RunningTables" },null);
            result.Results.ForEach(x=>x.WriteTo(new JsonTextWriter(Console.Out)));
```

It returns no document but when I use RavenDB Studio and execute the same query on `Raven/DocumentsByEntityName` index.

Then I took a look at my command Url and I realized start=30 so I changed the code as follow :

```
var result= store.DatabaseCommands.Query("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
                    new IndexQuery { Query = "Tag : RunningTables",Start=0 },null);
```

But nothing changed except that now Url doesn't contain start anymore.
What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I've got what was wrong with my Code.I didn't select the default database and there was more than one database in my RavenDB. So I did it like this :

```
var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080" , DefaultDatabase = "MyDbName" };
            store.Initialize();
            var result= store.DatabaseCommands.Query("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
                new IndexQuery { Query = "Tag : RunningTables" },null);
            result.Results.ForEach(x=>x.WriteTo(new JsonTextWriter(Console.Out)));
```